# Vertical center multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I need to center the content of an `li` vertically so what i did is a `lineheight` and it works but the problem is that when I have multiple lines, this technique no longer works and i `can't modify` the `html` since it's a constraint given by the professor. So i really ran out of solutions.

Here is the `HTML` And the `Css`

```css
    li
    {
    
        
     list-style-type:none; 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
     height: 55px;
     display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 55px;
    
    }
    ul
    {
     list-style : none;
      
    }
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>
             The 2015–16 UEFA Champions League was the 61st season of Europe's premier club football tournament organised by UEFA, and the 24th season since it was renamed from the European Champion Clubs' Cup to the UEFA Champions League
          
       </li>
  
    </ul>
```

Comment: Vertically align means?

Comment: Yes vertical align

Comment: You'll have to use one of the other 4 or 5 techniques for vertically centering your content. They're all well covered in many questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  height:  260px;
  width:   180px;
  padding: 10px;
  border:  2px solid darkgray;
}
.parent li {
  border:1px solid blue;
  display:        flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding:8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li>Something about Footbal</li>
  <li>Something about Footbal</li>
  <li>Something about Footbal</li>
</ul>
```

The position of the child element is related to his parent's `display` property. If the parent will have `display:table` , the child will have `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`.

We have more examples [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) and also [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: So just copy-paste the answer that you saw in the other question?

Comment: Repetition is the mother of all learning :)

Comment: one thing is repeating, the other is copy-pasting the code.

Comment: Ah , now i understood what do you mean dippas . Sorry , i edit now the answer

Comment: It's working but now my li are next to each other

Comment: But i want to have each li under each other li

Comment: Take a look now at the Snippet Brandon